# How to make sure changes in the database that happen within a transaction are also seen by everything within that transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I've got a transaction that saves or updates a set of objects in a database. This is the code:

```
@Transactional
public void updatePDBEntry(Set<PDBEntry> pdbEntrySet) {
    for (PDBEntry pdbEntry : pdbEntrySet) {
        PDBEntry existingEntry = findByAccessionCode(pdbEntry.getAccessionCode());
        if (existingEntry != null) {
            log.debug("Remove previous version of PDBEntry {}", existingEntry);
            makeTransient(existingEntry);
        }
        makePersistent(pdbEntry);
    }
}
```

And in the genericDAO:

```
public void makePersistent(I entity) {
    getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
}

public void makeTransient(I entity) {
    getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work, it says it can't insert the object because of a duplicate key, even though I can see in the logs that it gets to makeTransient(). I guess this has to do with the fact that all this is happening within a transaction, so the changes made by makeTransient() might not be seen by the makePersistent() method. I could solve this by copying all data from pdbEntry into existingEntry and then doing saveOrUpdate(existingEntry) but that is sort of a dirty hack. Is there another way to make sure the makeTransient is visible to makePersistent, while still keeping it all within a transaction?

EDIT: This is my PDBEntry domain model:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "accessionCode", "date" })
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
public class PDBEntry extends DomainObject implements Serializable {
    @NaturalId
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 4)
    private String          accessionCode;

    @NaturalId
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date            date;

    private String          header;

    private Boolean         isValidDssp;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date            lastUpdated     = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pdbEntry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ExpMethod       expMethod;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pdbEntry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Refinement> refinementSet   = new HashSet<Refinement>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pdbEntry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<HetGroup>   hetGroupSet     = new HashSet<HetGroup>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pdbEntry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Chain>      chainSet        = new HashSet<Chain>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pdbEntry", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Chain>      residueSet      = new HashSet<Chain>();

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return new Date(lastUpdated.getTime());
    }

    public void setLastUpdated() throws InvocationTargetException {
        throw new InvocationTargetException(new Throwable());
    }

    public void touch() {
        lastUpdated = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return accessionCode;
    }

    public PDBEntry(String accessionCode, Date date) throws NullPointerException {
        if (accessionCode != null && date != null) {
            this.accessionCode = accessionCode;
            this.date = date;
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DomainObject implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long    id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);

    @Override
    public abstract int hashCode();

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

EDIT: New problem, I've created a method that first deletes all the existing objects from the database like so:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updatePDBEntries(Set<PDBEntry> pdbEntrySet) {
    findAndRemoveExistingPDBEntries(pdbEntrySet);
    savePDBEntries(pdbEntrySet);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void findAndRemoveExistingPDBEntries(Set<PDBEntry> pdbEntrySet) {
    for (PDBEntry pdbEntry : pdbEntrySet) {
        PDBEntry existingPDBEntry = findByAccessionCode(pdbEntry.getAccessionCode());
        if (existingPDBEntry != null) {
            log.info("Delete: {}", pdbEntry);
            makeTransient(existingPDBEntry);
        }
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void savePDBEntries(Set<PDBEntry> pdbEntrySet) {
    for (PDBEntry pdbEntry : pdbEntrySet) {
        log.info("Save: {}", pdbEntry);
        makePersistent(pdbEntry);
    }
}
```

It seems to delete the first 73 entries it encounters, but then gives an error:

```
WARN  2010-10-25 14:28:49,406 main JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
ERROR 2010-10-25 14:28:49,406 main JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Batch entry 0 /* delete nl.ru.cmbi.pdbeter.core.model.domain.PDBEntry */ delete from PDBEntry where id='74' was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
WARN  2010-10-25 14:28:49,406 main JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
ERROR 2010-10-25 14:28:49,406 main JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - ERROR: update or delete on table "pdbentry" violates foreign key constraint "fke03a2dc84d44e296" on table "hetgroup"
  Detail: Key (id)=(74) is still referenced from table "hetgroup".
ERROR 2010-10-25 14:28:49,408 main AbstractFlushingEventListener:324 - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Any ideas how this error might arise?

EDIT: I found the problem: the last error was caused by the hetgroup model, which is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "pdbEntry", "hetId" })
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedPrivateField")
// extends DomainObject which contains Id, NaturalId is not enough in this case, since duplicate chains still exist
// in fact this is an error of the PDBFinder and will be fixed in the future
public class HetGroup extends DomainObject implements Serializable {
    //@NaturalId 
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private PDBEntry    pdbEntry;

    //@NaturalId 
    @NotEmpty
    private String hetId;

    private  Integer nAtom;

    @Length(max = 8192)
    private String name;

    public HetGroup(PDBEntry pdbEntry, String hetId) {
        this.pdbEntry = pdbEntry;
        pdbEntry.getHetGroupSet().add(this);

        this.hetId = hetId;
    }
}
```

Especially pay attention to the commented @NaturalId's, I commented these because there was still some error in my data that caused duplicate hetgroups, so I thought I'd just remove the UNIQUE constraint on them for now, but I forgot that I was using Lombok to create equals and hashcode methods for me, as can be seen from the line:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "pdbEntry", "hetId" })
```

This caused the error with the duplicate HetId's. I fixed the data and reinstated the @NaturalId's, and now everything works fine.

Thanks all!

Comment: what is the primary key of PDBEntry?

Comment: Also what is your key generating strategy on PDBEntry?

Comment: The primary key is a generated ID, though there is a UNIQUE constraint on 2 fields of the PDBEntry object.

Comment: The generating strategy is IDENTITY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somehow this doesn't work, it says it can't insert the object because of a duplicate key, even though I can see in the logs that it gets to makeTransient().

To understand what is happening here, you need first to understand that Hibernate doesn't immediately write changes to the database, **changes are enqueued in the session and written at `flush` time**. So even if you see that `makeTransient()` is called, this doesn't mean the corresponding record has been actually deleted from the database at the time the method is called. The SQL delete statement, and other pending change(s) will be executed when the `flush` will occur (either by explicitly calling `flush()`, at `commit()` time, or **when performing a HQL query**). This is well explained in the documentation:

> #### [10.10. Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)
>
> Sometimes the Session will execute the
>   SQL statements needed to synchronize
>   the JDBC connection's state with the
>   state of objects held in memory. This
>   process, called *flush*, occurs by
>   default at the following points:
>
> - **before some query executions**
> - from `org.hibernate.Transaction.commit()`
> - from `Session.flush()`
>
> The SQL statements are issued in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. **all entity insertions in the same order the corresponding objects were
>      saved using `session.save()`**
> 2. all entity updates
> 3. all collection deletions
> 4. all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
> 5. all collection insertions
> 6. **all entity deletions in the same order the corresponding objects were
>      deleted using `Session.delete()`**
>
> An exception is that objects using
>   native ID generation are inserted when
>   they are saved.
>
> ...

So, let's look again at your code:

```
01: @Transactional
02: public void updatePDBEntry(Set<PDBEntry> pdbEntrySet) {
03:     for (PDBEntry pdbEntry : pdbEntrySet) {
04:         PDBEntry existingEntry = findByAccessionCode(pdbEntry.getAccessionCode());
05:         if (existingEntry != null) {
06:             log.debug("Remove previous version of PDBEntry {}", existingEntry);
07:             makeTransient(existingEntry);
08:         }
09:         makePersistent(pdbEntry);
10:     }
11: }
```

- at 04, you perform a query (this will flush pending changes if any)
- at 07, you perform a `session.delete()` (in memory)
- at 09, you perform a `session.save()` (in memory)
- back to 04, changes are flushed and Hibernate issues SQL statements in the above specified order

  - and the insert fail because of a key violation because the record hasn't been deleted yet

In other words, your problem has nothing to do with transactions, it's just related to the way Hibernate works and the way you use it.

> Is there another way to make sure the makeTransient is visible to makePersistent, while still keeping it all within a transaction?

Well, without changing the logic, you could help Hibernate and `flush()` explicitly after the `delete()`.

But IMO, the whole approach is is suboptimal and you should update the existing record if any instead of delete then insert (unless there are good reasons to do so).

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [10.10. Flushing the Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-flushing)

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because I build the actual PDBEntry objects somewhere else. To be able to update I need to check if it exists in the database first, grab it, and use that instance instead of creating a new one. The problem I have now is that I'm running batches of 100 PDBEntries at a time, so to be able to check the existence of all the entries I'd need some way of either doing this during the batch process that fills/updates the PDBEntries, or right before that and then for all the entries in the batch, mapped to the rawDataEntries that will go into the PDBEntries.

Comment: The first choice might be nice, but for that to work with my current DAO it would need to create a new transaction for every search operation in the database which checks for the existence of a specific PDBEntry. The latter method can be done entirely within the DAO, by taking Set<rawPDBEntry> as argument, and returning Map<rawPDBEntry, PDBEntry>. That way I can check for the existence of a PDBEntry in a batch without being in the DAO and still being able to perform that check for the entire batch within one transaction, but it seems ugly. What do you think?

Comment: @FinalArt2005: Well, I think you found a solution :) My point was more to strictly explain the problem exposed in your question, and the title.

Comment: Ok :) And yes, I was hoping someone could shed some light on that, and you did, so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

The single transaction should not be the problem.

Your suggestion - copy the data from pdbEntry into existingEntry is a far better solution. It's a lot less database intensive for one and a little easier to read and understand what is going on.

Also, if you did it this way, you would not be required to do a saveOrUpdate on the changed object. Hibernate implements what is known as "transparent persistence"... which means that hibernate is responsible for working out what data operations need to be employed to synchronise the object with the database. The "Update" operation in hibernate is not for objects that are already persistent. see [here](http://analysis102.blogspot.com/2008/12/hibernate-what-does-update-actually.html)

The code would in this case look like this (note not updated required):

```
    public void updatePDBEntry(Set<PDBEntry> pdbEntrySet) {
        for (PDBEntry pdbEntry : pdbEntrySet) {
            PDBEntry existingEntry = findByAccessionCode(pdbEntry.getAccessionCode());
            if (existingEntry != null) {
                // copy relevant fields from pdbEntry to existing Entry - preferably with a method on PDBEntry
            } else {
                makePersistent(pdbEntry); // although better to just call _save_ (not saveOrUpdate) cause you know it's a new object
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: I tried this just now, but I'm getting a lot of new errors when I do this. Also it would mean I'd have to put this copying code in all the domain models. Even though it costs a little bit more for the database to first cascade remove an entry and then inserting a new one instead of updating the existing one, this way I'm absolutely sure (if everything else works that is) that there are no pieces of old data left in the database.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that a bit: I have a domain model for pdbEntry that has several OneToMany relations. These are represented within the pdbEntry domain model as sets. If I make a data-copying-function in the pdbEntry model, how do I make sure the sets get copied as well? Does Hibernate understand something like: set = newPDBEntry.set? I mean does it remove all the current objects in the set and create the new ones? Also I was getting a nullPointerException for a oneToOne related object, it said that constraints dictate it can't be null, but it's the exact same object that I added before, I'm

Comment: just sending the same batch of objects to the database twice to test whether the second time this updating mechanism kicks in and is working, so how can this same object now have a field that contains null while it should? If you still think that copying the data is the best option, then I'll have to solve all these errors, otherwise I'll need to find an answer to my original question...

Comment: in that case, first make sure that you delete operation is working 100%. What you could consider is make a pass going through and deleting all the objects that you have new ones for, and then inserting those. i.e. make a delete pass and then an insert one.

Comment: Do you mean for every relation within an entry, or just going through all, deleting the existing ones in one transaction and then another transaction in which the entries are inserted?